# LinqToSQL needs explicity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to populate a datagrid with a list of items retrieved from a LinqToSQL statement and something is causing a bit of confusion for me.

When I explicitly set a where clause to be equal to a hard-coded integer the list is returned without any issues. However, when I use an object with a property that contains the same integer, the list is returned but the datagrid does not populate.

The list that is being returned has, I am assuming private and public properties. The hard-coded integer return list contains all of the properties, whereas the object with the property return list contains only the private properties and the public properties are stating "Function evaluation is disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out"

```
Example:
```

> ```
>      object.country
>             _countryid
>             _continentid
>             _countryname
>             CountryID
>             ContinentID
>             CountryName
> ```

Here are the two LinqToSQL statements (Both are returning a list of items, but only one is not throwing an error):

**Working LinqToSQL Statement**

```
protected void rgcountry_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<db_entity.country> _clist;
    using (db_era.era_entities _ee = new db_era.era_entities())
    {
        _clist = (from a in _ee.countries where a.ContinentID == 4 select a).ToList();
    }
    if (_clist.Count > 0)
        this.rgcountry.DataSource = _clist;
    else
        this.rgcountry.DataSource = empty();
}
```

**Non-Working LinqToSQL statement - (continentselected is set and continentID does have a value)**

```
protected void rgcountry_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<db_entity.country> _clist;
    if (continentselected != null)
    {
        using (db_era.era_entities _ee = new db_era.era_entities())
        {
            _clist = (from a in _ee.countries where a.ContinentID == continentselected.ContinentID select a).ToList();
        }
        if (_clist.Count > 0)
            this.rgcountry.DataSource = _clist;
        else
            this.rgcountry.DataSource = empty();
    }
    else
        this.rgcountry.DataSource = empty();
}
```

What am I missing here? Or this the way LinqToSQL works?

Comment: Is there any logic in the ContinentID getter? I also don't see a call to databind...

Comment: Did you make sure continentselected.ContinentID actually has a valid value? Since it's integer, it's 0 by default. Did you make sure it's set to 4?

Comment: @Stephen Panzer: For a Telerik RadGrid you do not need a databind. What do you mean by the ContinentID getter exactly?

Comment: @neo: yes I am positive continentselected.ContinentID does have a valid value. The ranges are from 1 to 7 as we have 7 continents in our DB. And the continentselected is set when another datagrid item is selected. This I am sure of.

Comment: @mattgcon: I do this sort of query with devexpress grids without a problem. What are types for continentselected and continentselected.ContinentID?

Comment: @mattgcon ContinentID appears to be a property which exposes the explicit, private _continentid backing field. Does the property have any logic in the getter beyond just a 'return _continentid'?

Comment: @StephenPanzer: there is no logic as all beyond just a return. The entity database was created using Telerik wizard. So the explicit is the fields without the "_" I am assuming. And yes ContinentID is a property for the continent object from the continent table

Comment: @neo continentselected is of type continent from entity and the ContinentID is a property (column) for type continent

Comment: @mattgcon: What is property's type?

Comment: oh the property type is byte.

Comment: byte is a weird type to give to such a column. In your hardcoded example, you assign integer. Then you try to have the same effect with byte type. How is that possible?

Comment: @neo HAHA I don't know how it's possible that is why I am totally stumped on this one.

Comment: byte and integer are like apple and orange. Not the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84012/discussion-between-mattgcon-and-neo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following. **continentselected** is retrieved using different data context. And you create a new data context for your query by saying

```
using (db_era.era_entities _ee = new db_era.era_entities())
```

and **continentselected** doesn't belong to that context.
Linq to sql wouldn't perform with entities from different data contexts. For your query, use the same data context that you used to retrieve **continentselected** entity instance

Comment: This wont be possible, since the **continentselected** comes from another datagrid populated before this one is populated, and both grids are in separate user controls. I even extracted the continentID and placed it into a new variable (i.e. byte conID) essentially just passing a byte to a.ContinentID and it still cuases the same issue.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say "continentselected comes from another datagrid"? Grid can give you its row data and grids usually return type object.

Comment: The country grid is on a webpage with another grid (continent) which is initially loaded on loading of the Page. Then the user is to select the continent which then loads the country grid. Telerik grids are a little weird as they return datakeyvalues not types of objects places in the grid.

Comment: Don't you use that datakey value in order to retrieve the actual row data?

Comment: No the other way around, when the row is selected it passes the griditem and the way to get the values is specify which datakey you want to get.

Comment: You say that the value you get from the grid for continentselected.ContinentID is byte. This doesn't make sense. make it return int and you would be fine with your where condition.

Comment: Ok I will try that and let you know.